# usage details api using azure app registration in azure AD

Tags: azure, postman

In basic terms, I am trying to get an access token to get Azure Cost Centre Data through the Usage Details API. The problem is that I can't seem to configure my service principal with azure properly. I have:

1. Created the registered app in Azure Active Directory
2. added https://www.thunderclient.io/oauth/callback in the redirect URL
3. generated a client secret
4. Included the following information in my *Generate New Token* in Thunder  Client:

Request URL:
GET: [https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroupName/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.CostManagement/dimensions?api-version=2019-11-01](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7Bsubscription-id%7D/resourceGroupName/%7BresourceGroupName%7D/providers/Microsoft.CostManagement/dimensions?api-version=2019-11-01)

- Grant Type: Authorization Code
- Auth Url: https://login.mmicrosoftonline.com/common/oauthorize
- Token Url: [https://login.microsoft.com/{tenant-id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize](https://login.microsoft.com/%7Btenant-id%7D/oauth2/v2.0/authorize) *from app registration*
- callback Url: https://thunderclient.io/oauth/callback
- client ID: {{client_id}} *from app registration*
- client secret: {{client_secret}} *from app registration*
- scope: user_impersonation

{
Status 401 Unauthorized
"error": {
"code": "AuthenticationFailed",
"message": Authentication failed."
}
}

Header:

Bearer authorization_uri "https://login.windows.net/{tenant_id}, error= "invalid_token", error description="Could not find identity for access token"

Comment: Did you give `Azure Service Management API` permission to your Service Principal? Also, you will need to assign appropriate role (try with Reader first) to the Service Principal in the concerned Azure Subscription.

Comment: if it's just general azure cost centre info, what does the service principal need reader access to?

Comment: To execute Azure Management API, you would need to assign appropriate role to a user (Service Principal in this case) on the Subscription.

Comment: okay, and it has to be at the subscription level? Because my scope for the get request is at the resource group level. I have assigned the server principal reader access on the resource group, and I still get the same 401 unauthorized error.

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide the details (like your request URL etc.) there? Please obfuscate any sensitive information before sharing.

Comment: sorry about that, I had another look at the post and saw I was limitted in how much text I can put in, should be good now with the added responses for the error piece. There is something wrong wtih the access token, and I'm not sure what.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. And big thanks to Guarav Mantri in the comments below.

The Scope should be set to https://management.azure.com/.default
The Grant Type is  client credentials and not authorization code
The service principal needs to be added to the resource in azure that is part of the request (i.e. if looking for subscription data, then add the service principal as a reader role to the subscription).